# How to pass empty value when enum is expected in swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uikit

I can't figure out how to not pass any options to the `option:` parameter in `UIView.animateWithDuration` In obj-C would simply pass `0`, but the compiler won't allow that. I've tried passing `nil`, `0`, `()`, and `_`. This is using the latest version of Swift with Xcode beta 7.1 
Thanks

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, 
        delay: 0, 
        usingSpringWithDamping: 1, 
        initialSpringVelocity: 0, 
        options: //what goes here??? ,

        animations: { () -> Void in

            let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(360)
            self.titleLabel.transform = transform

        },

        completion: { (finished) -> Void in

        })

}
```

Comment: i tried `nil` as well. I'm on Swift 2.0, which probably matters. I'll update my question.

Comment: Pass `[]` in Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIViewAnimationOptions conforms to the OptionSetType protocol so you should give an array of the options you want and if you don't want any you can give an empty array.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.4,
            options: [],
            animations: {

            }) { finished in

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `nil` for this parameter if you don't want any options.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut` (as it is the default anyways) or `nil`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

UIView.animateWithDuration(3, 
    delay: 0, 
    usingSpringWithDamping: 1, 
    initialSpringVelocity: 0, 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut ,

    animations: { () -> Void in

        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(360)
        self.titleLabel.transform = transform

    },

    completion: { (finished) -> Void in

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **pass any animation option** such:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
```

and a lot other options, you can check them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)

if you **don't need it** you can pass `nil`